# Get Dopdownlist value based on SelectedIndex

Tags: c#

How to Select Value from Particular Index i.e. 0, 1st , 2nd ,3rd or 4th of DropDownList.

Using C#.

I have a DropDownList which have 6 items, now I like to Select 4th item form that DropDownList.

Note that the value of this item is unknown; as it may change time to time; but I know that it will be at 4th place in dropdown.

I this my try, which not working

> string Item4;
>
> item4 = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 3;

Comment: How is it not working ? Do you get an error ? Unexpected results ?

Comment: Also, is this ASP .NET or WinForms ? AS I recall, there is a DropDownList class in both. It would be nice not having to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string item4 = DropDownList1.Items[3].Value;

 item4 = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 3; is not correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

string item4 = DropDownList1.Items[3].Value;

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of Dropdown via index use below:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

To get the value from the dropdown use:

```
String Value = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
```

And for text use :

```
String Text = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var listItem = dropDownList.Items[3];
var value = listItem.Value;
```

Comment: this will select the 5th item

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 3;
string item = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

So many answers here

```
ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items[3];
string value = item.Value;
string text = item.Text;
```